# UEFI only laptop (no legacy boot) says no operating system found

Tags: boot, lubuntu, uefi, usb-installation

I am attempting to change the HP Envy x2 over to Lubuntu but I am having a bit of a struggle. When I start the computer it says it does not detect any operating system (I created a bootable USB using lubuntu alternative 18.04 with Rufus). I cleaned my usb and converted it to GPT and still nothing. I assume this has to do with the laptop only having UEFI and no legacy boot mode (A individual told me he solved this my enabling legacy boot mode which my laptop does not have). All help is appreciated! (lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386)

Comment: I am really sorry I meant to say 18.04 haha

Comment: I am attempting to install lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386

Comment: Why not pick a 64 bit lubuntu for your 64 bit computer?

Comment: I don't think the Envy X2 is 64 bit.

Comment: I'll download the 64 bit version when I get home and try it out.

Comment: Nope doesn't work?

Comment: Doesn't work how?  What error?  (ie. is it a kernel message on non-PAE?, non x86_64 error?) Specifics help us to understand your situation. I don't know the alternate lubuntu installer, but I recall some of the alternate installers handle fewer cases so I'd try using the regular installer. I had trouble with a sony vaio (very limited bios/uefi) & just installed using defaults & it worked. I then took notes of what was done (/boot/efi/ I recall for me), then re-installed it closer to what I wanted.

Comment: So the main problem I was having was it just said there was no operating system detected. I then added a file called bootia32.efi and I now get it to find the operating system and boot. Now it boots into GNU Grub and presents me with options to install lubuntu, rescue, oem install and one other. When I press install lubuntu it goes to a page that then says "booting "install lubuntu".

Comment: I have been following this link here https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/91f091/tutoriallinux_x64_on_baytrail_32bit_efilenovo/ but get different result when launching

Comment: I forgot to add it just gets stuck on booting install lubuntu

Comment: I also just tried installing multiarch ISO and the full install screen comes up but it freezes when I choose something. Not sure what is happening but what ever I do it freezes when I chose any option on any distro.

Comment: For UEFI only I extract the ISO file to FAT32 USB using 7Zip. Best to confirm MD5SUM of ISO file. This works in Windows or in Ubuntu using P7Zip or Archive Manager.

Comment: Once I get home I will extract it to the FAT32 USB using that method. I assume the partition needs to be GPT as well?

Comment: @ExileVoid : The ISO Extract files must be on FAT32 partition, the partition table may be MSDOS or GPT. For booting a hybrid ISO File, the partition table must be msdos.

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply but the same thing happens. As soon as I press enter on any of the options (Any install options) it freezes.

Comment: Also I checked the MD5sum and it matched with the one downloaded from the site.

Comment: I found something rather interesting and I am not sure if it could help. But I was trying to boot into the fedora 27 iso. I made a bootable usb in all ways possible. NTFS MBR/NTFS GPT/FAT32 GPT/FAT32 MBR and I found that when I was in NTFS MBR (rufus created two partitions which was E: and D:) the computer would read everything in the E: perfectly but was not able to detect D:. Here is a image of the drives. https://ibb.co/F0xJGnn As I said I am not sure if this means anything important.